# vertx RecordParser exception handling

Tags: java, vert.x

I am using a `NetServer` in Vertx and when a new client is connected a flowable is created emitting packets that are received on that `NetClient`. In order to figure out how to do proper exception handling I have added some random exceptions into the flow:

```
private RecordParser createParser(NetState state, FlowableEmitter<Buffer> emitter) {
    RecordParser parser = RecordParser.newFixed(4);
    parser.handler(buffer -> {
        if(Math.random() > 0.8) {
            logger.error("I am dying now");
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        // protocol handling
    }).exceptionHandler((throwable) -> {
        logger.error("Got an exception: ", throwable);
        emitter.onError(throwable);
    });
    return parser;
}
```

I use this like this:

```
NetState state = new NetState();
// client -> NetClient
return Flowable.create(emitter -> client.handler(createParser(state, emitter)), BackpressureStrategy.ERROR);
```

Now the problem is, my exception thrown in the record parser never reaches any exception handler. Neither the one of the `RecordParser` itself nor the one I had attached to the `client`. It goes all up to the root context. How do I catch exceptions that occur during record parsing (in order to close the client that sent invalid data for example)